# Courier IMAP cannot find my Maildir but can find root's Maildir

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, imap, maildir, courier

I'm running into a weird issue setting up Postfix and Courier IMAP on a clean Ubuntu 13.04 install. I'm using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto), and am currently [Testing Courier IMAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Testing_Courier_IMAP).

When I try to login with root, everything's fine (this is part of a netcat connection):

```
a login root my-pass
a OK LOGIN Ok.
a logout
* BYE Courier-IMAP server shutting down
a OK LOGOUT completed
```

However, when I try to login with my own account, I get an error:

```
a login camilstaps my-other-pass
* BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: No such file or directory: No such file or directory
```

The mail.log:

```
Jun  2 13:47:37 cs imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] # this is the root login
Jun  2 13:47:51 cs imapd: LOGIN, user=root, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], port=[54630], protocol=IMAP
Jun  2 13:48:11 cs imapd: LOGOUT, user=root, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], headers=0, body=0, rcvd=9, sent=80, time=20
Jun  2 13:50:59 cs imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] # this is the other login
Jun  2 13:51:07 cs imapd: chdir Maildir: No such file or directory
Jun  2 13:51:07 cs imapd: camilstaps: No such file or directory
```

And the mail.err, not really adding something:

```
Jun  2 13:51:07 cs imapd: camilstaps: No such file or directory
```

I configured Postfix to use the Maildir format using `/var/mail/%u` where `%u` is the username. At first, I thought the camilstaps user missed his mail folder. However, it does have one similar to root's one:

```
root@cs:/# tree -CdA /var/mail
/var/mail
├── camilstaps
│   └── Maildir
│       ├── cur
│       ├── new
│       └── tmp
└── root
    └── Maildir
        ├── cur
        ├── new
        └── tmp
```

Then I thought the camilstaps user had a different maildir in the MAIL constant, however...

```
root@cs:/# echo $MAIL
/var/mail/root
camilstaps@cs:/$ echo $MAIL
/var/mail/camilstaps
```

What's going on here? How can I fix this?

<sub>For what it's worth, I'm on Ubuntu Server 13.04.</sub>

---

With help from the comments, I found out something interesting / possibly useful:

- There was an old Maildir in `/root`. When I remove that one, I get the same error when logging in as root to the IMAP server.
- When I add a Maildir directory to the homedir of the camilstaps user, I don't get the error anymore.

For some reason, the IMAP server doesn't look in `/var/mail/%u` (`%u` = username) but in `%h/Maildir` (`%h` = homedir). The `$MAIL` variable has been set correctly, so what could be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct configuration file? What happens if you create `Maildir` in `/home/camilstaps`?

Comment: @tripleee I'm working with `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, that is correct, right? When I create Maildir in /home/camilstaps, I get the same error. I think I understand what you're hitting at. I tried removing /root/Maildir and now I get the same error for root!

Comment: @tripleee right, the homedir of the camilstaps user isn't /home/camilstaps. When I do add a Maildir to the homedir of camilstaps, it works. However, I want the Maildirs to be in /var/mail. The environment variables are set okay, so what's going on?

Comment: The IMAP server is not examining the user's interactive environment at all.  If IMAP is running as user `mail` then the `mail` user's environment variables are what's visible to the server.

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Do you mean I need to set IMAP as user `mail`? How do I do that?

Comment: No, I'm saying that whatever user it's running as does not have access to your environment.  You seem to be attempting to solve the wrong problem, anyway.  Instead of try to figure out what somebody's `MAIL` is set to, you should configure Postfix, the IMAP server, and the shell to all agree on where mail is being delivered, then have the shell set each user's `MAIL` based on that agreement.

Comment: @tripleee hm, but I'm running IMAP as root (or at least via the `sudo -s` command)

Comment: Running Courier IMAP with user Maildirs outside `$HOME` appears to be poorly supported.  I found http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12858 but not much else on the topic.

Comment: @tripleee thanks a lot! That explains it. I guess I'll just go with Virtual Mailboxes than. Would you like to write a short answer that this isn't really supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It appears](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12858) that Courier IMAP's architecture does not support Maildirs outside of `$HOME`.